# JSON Schema - anyOf within conditional?

Tags: conditional-statements, jsonschema, any

I am trying to define a JSON schema with conditionals. I built an MVE which already doesn't work as I expect it.

The object I want to validate is:

```
{
  "keiner": false, 
  "abdominal": true,
  "zervikal": false
}
```

The conditional rule is simple. When "keiner" is true, both other values have to be false. If "keiner" is false, at least one of the other two has to be true.

I wrote this schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "keiner": { "type": "boolean" },
    "abdominal": { "type": "boolean" }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "keiner": { "const": true }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties" : {
      "abdominal": { "const": false },
      "zervikal": {"const": false }
    }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "abdominal": { "const": true } },
        { "zervikal": { "const" : true } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But the Newtonsoft online validator gives the error message

> Unexpected token encountered when reading value for 'anyOf'. Expected StartObject, Boolean, got StartArray.

for the line in which ´anyOf´ starts. This confuses me, as all examples I can find show anyOf followed by an array of options.

So what am I doing wrong? Why cannot I have a startArray after anyOf, and how do I write the schema correctly?

Comment: anyOf as a schema keyword would expect an array of sub-schemas. However, you used anyOf as child of the schema keyword "properties". So actually you are defining a property with the name "anyOf". And this would require a schema which could be an object or boolean.

Comment: @Clemens I see your point - do you know the correct place for 'anyOf' if it is not inside the properties object? I also tried placing it inside the 'else', but it produced an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the schema you are looking for:

[image: Corrected JSON schema in JSONBuddy]

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was able to go from there and build on it. Apparently my second approach (now edited in) was almost correct, but I had to wrap each array element in curly brackets. Getting closer to the syntax step by step :)

Comment: I noticed a small thing missing, one also needs a "required" at the end - I didn't feel like it deserves its own answer, so I added it to yours.